# maven direct dependency on two versions of the same object in one project

Tags: maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a case where I need to build what could be considered a patch between 2 versions of the same object.  I am using Maven 3.1.1

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact1</artifactId>
    <!-- managed version from parent pom -->
    <!-- 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT -->
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

I use the maven-dependency-plugin to unzip them into different directories during the build process.  The exec-maven-plugin is used to execute an external tool that creates what is essentially a patch.

**This all works.**

The problem is a warning

```
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for my.group.id:build-patch:pom:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: my.group.id:artifact1:zip -> version (?) vs 1.0.0 @ my.group.id:build-patch:[unknown-version], /my/jenkins/workspace/directory/stuff/build-patch/pom.xml, line 163, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
```

**I know this is only a warning**

However I want to make the build as clean as possible.  Also note that the groupId:artifactId:type:classifier will never be unique.  How can I set this up so that there are no warnings?  Does anyone else suspect that this may be a problem in the future?